# I'm having a hard time terminating a java loop

Tags: java, loops

I'm sure if you read the snippet you'll understand what I'm trying to do. However, I tried it first with `null` and `""`. I think `.eoln()` won't work because I'm asking for multiple lines of input, of which all have an end of line. I would preferably have the loop terminate when the user returns an empty line. For some more background, I've used the `==`/`!=` and `.equals()` operators/method to experiment. I also just tried a `do/while` to no avail.

The asterisks were added to test if the empty string was an issue for the while statement.

Can anyone explain what I clearly don't understand about Java/TextIO yet?

EDIT - Revised Code Snippet:

```
  while(write){
        pl("Begin writing content to fill file.");
        pl("");
        pl("Return a line with a single SPACE or"); 
        pl("\"\\n\" to represent line breaks in your");
        pl("");
        pl("Return two asterisks ** when done writing,");
        pl("and you will be then prompted to select a file");
        pl("to save your writing to.");


        String input = TextIO.getln();;
        String value = new String();
        while(!(input.equals(""))) {
            if (input == " " || input == "\\n") {
                value += "\\n" + "\\n";
            } else {
                value += input + " ";
            } // end if/else //
            input = TextIO.getln();
        } // end while(input) //
        TextIO.writeUserSelectedFile();
        p(value);
        TextIO.writeStandardOutput();
        pl("Would you like to write to another file?");
        Boolean cont = TextIO.getBoolean();
        write = cont;   
     }
  }
```

Comment: Compare strings with `equals()` not `==`.

Comment: It still won't break the loop on the expected terminal input.

Comment: input variable is string?

Comment: You are not changing your `input` within the loop, so it will never equal `**`.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Is it legal to set the condition, and then define input within the loop?

Comment: You are not supposed to redeclare it (write a new `String input` statement), but you *are* supposed to assign new values to it, otherwise, the loop won't work.

Comment: Can you give more details? Eg: where does the input value come from? What is it's original format?

Comment: So, given that `input = TextIO.getln();`,calling that again at the end of the statement would be bad taste? Should I omit it before the loop, and just call it once at the beginning?

Comment: Not in bad taste at all. That's how it's done. And you usually can't omit it before the loop otherwise checking the condition won't work.

Comment: Thank you. Java is not as intimidating as I think it is usually. I see it as a whole new world, when a lot of the concepts are relative to JavaScript (as far as loops and such go), and I have a decent understanding of these concepts. It's all very new to me, but I'm learning that it's also somewhat familiar. Thanks again. Also I added the entire loop in question.

Comment: I meant to also ask about returning a null line, as opposed to the asterisks.